# How to calculate the confidence interval of a regression prediction given a particular value for a binary predictor?

Tags: regression, self-study, confidence-interval

I have a regression predicting wage (dependent variable) from whether the participant is a college graduate (dummy variable, independent).

I have the regression coefficients and their standard errors, the R-squared of the regression, and the covariance between the intercept and the coefficient on the dummy variable.

How do I calculate a confidence interval for the average wage of a college graduate (given that dummy = 1)?

Comment: Which of these statistics do you think would be relevant to your question and why?  (Answering this might help you make some immediate progress.)

Comment: What is the size of the interval? 95%? How does your teacher / textbook define a confidence interval? What formulas have you found that you don't understand?

Comment: Yes, it's a 95% confidence interval. I'm not sure how it would be defined - it's considered review, and was given in a problem set without any explanation in class. I've looked at pages such as this one: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/297 , but these formulas don't quite seem relevant, and none contain the covariance. I'm not sure how to find the standard deviation for the entire regression, given what we know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: (a) If you did not have any regression at all, just the mean, the sample size, and the variance, could you calculate the confidence interval? If not, review confidence intervals. (b) How has the regression changed what you plug into the confidence interval formula in (a)?

Comment: Hmm, I can find the mean from the regression and I know the sample size, but how would I get the standard deviation if I only have the standard errors for college graduates and for non-college graduate? I found a sentence that says "In general, if the variables are correlated, then the variance of their sum is the sum of their covariances:" Does this mean the covariance is simply the variance for the overall regression that I would use in the hypothesis test?

Comment: See my answer which I think explains how to answer all your questions.

Comment: Metrix, I think you may have misquoted: the variance of the sum is the sum of the *variances* (not "covariances") if and only if the variables are *uncorrelated* (not "correlated").

Comment: I saw this in a wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables . Thanks, I will think about this and confirm with other sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Understanding** what's going on comes down to appreciating the distinctions between parameters, random variables, and realizations of random variables.  **Getting an answer** comes down to using this understanding to identify the pieces of information that are needed and knowing enough about the computer output to find those pieces.

---

Your model is in the form

$$\text{wage} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{[college graduate]}.$$

This assumes $\text{[college graduate]}$ is coded as $1$ for grads and $0$ for non-grads.

**The first step** in solving such problems is to figure out what combination of coefficients corresponds to what you're estimating.  Because that's the easy part, and it will be hard to go on without answering it, I will point out that the "average wage of a college graduate" is obtained by plugging in the dummy value for college grads, giving $\beta_0 + \beta_1 \times 1$ = $\beta_0 + \beta_1$.

**The second step** is recognizing that *you do not know either $\beta_0$ or $\beta_1$*. You estimate them from the data.  The regression results include their estimates, which we may call $b_0$ and $b_1$, respectively.  Because they are likely to differ from the betas, *we model the wages as random variables.*  Because both $b_0$ and $b_1$ are computed from these data, *they are realizations of random variables, too.*  Let's call these random variables $B_0$ and $B_1$.  Got that?

OK, if not, let's note that if you have standardized your x-values in the regression (to make the formulas simpler), then the formula for $b_0$ is that it's the average of all the $y$-values:

$$b_0 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i y_i.$$

We are viewing the $y_i$ as realizations of random variables $Y_i$ (the wages for each subject in the dataset).  Thus, $b_0$ is the realization of the average random variable

$$B_0 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i Y_i.$$

When you make assumptions about the distributions of the $Y_i$, this formula lets you determine how those assumptions affect the distribution of $B_0$. You would usually be most interested in the expected value and the variance of $B_0$: the expectation tells you what $\beta_0$ ought to be, more or less, and the variance (once you take its square root) tells you how close $b_0$ ought to come to $\beta_0$.

Similar reasoning (but with more complicated formulas) holds for $\beta_1$.

(Fortunately, you will not need to work through all the mathematics to relate the expectations and variances of the $B_i$ to those of the $Y_i$: the regression procedure does that for you.)

The upshot is that *the fitted regression coefficients $b_0$ and $b_1$ are realizations of random variables.*  You are interested in how much $b_0 + b_1$ might vary, because (obviously) this is your estimate of $\beta_0 + \beta_1$.  To that end you would want to find out two things (**the third step**):

1. What is the expected value of $B_0 + B_1$?  (Hint: regression theory tells you what this is in terms of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$.)
2. How much should $B_0 + B_1$ vary around its expectation?

To answer #2, you would like to find the *variance* of the random variable $B_0+B_1$ (and then take its square root).  You know, from basic principles governing covariances, that the variance of $B_0+B_1$ can be computed from the variance-covariance matrix of $(B_0, B_1)$, and you should know how to do this.

This reasoning reduces the problem to:

*Using the regression output, how can you reconstruct the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients?*

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! Very detailed and useful.

Answer (score 0):

The link you gave derives the correct formula for you. It explains it quite clearly. The MSE is used to estimated the variance σ$^2$. Remember that the regression model assumes homoscedasticity which means the variance is the same for the college graduates as it is for the non-college graduates.

Comment: Good to know that I'm on the right track. I'm still a little confused though, because the link calculates a lot of parameters using software, and I need to do them by hand. What would the x- xbar parameter be? Is it the difference between college and non-college grad wages? Also, I didn't seem to find anything about the covariance in the MSE-related formulas. Do you mean that the variance is not related to the individual standard errors?

Comment: the square root of the pooled variance is the standrad error that is used.  Because you assume the variances are the same the pooled variance is used rather than a combination of the individual variances.

Comment: Ok, I will try doing this, but what does x-xbar refer to?

Comment: X is the dummy variable in your case 1 for college graduates and 0 for non-graduates.  So Xbar is the proportion of the data that correspond to college graduates.

Comment: That formula is for a *prediction* interval, not a confidence interval!

Comment: @whuber I am not sure what you are referring to.  I am referring to the confidence interval equation for y^ given in the linked Penn State tutorial that the OP gave.  That is for a confidence interval or else it would have an addition +1 under the sqaure root sign if it were for a prediction interval.  In either case x-xbar appears in the formula be it for confidence intervals or prediction interval.  My comment was to make the analogy to the OP for the case where his X is a dummy variable. Did I say something wrong?

Comment: Michael, you are right: I thought I saw that "+1" but it just isn't there.  I was puzzling over how it could be related to the problem, though: regression output rarely provides all the data needed to apply that formula.