# Reference level and Interpretation

Tags: interpretation

Suppose that we have a categorical variable $X$ that can take three values: $0$, $1$, or $2$. We use $X=0$ as the reference level. The following dummy variables are created: $$X_1 = 1 \ \text{if} \ X=1 \ \text{or} \ X_1=0 \ \text{if} \ X \neq 1$$

$$X_2 = 1 \ \text{if} \ X=2 \ \text{or} \ X_2=0 \ \text{if} \ X \neq 2$$

In a linear regression model, suppose we have $$Y = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \epsilon$$

We know that $\beta_1$ compares $X=1$ vs $X=0$ and $\beta_2$ compares $X=2$ vs $X=0$. How would we get the coefficients that compares $X=2$ vs $X=1$? Would it be $\beta_1+\beta_2$?

Comment: You don't mean B2-B1?

Comment: @Charles: How did you get that?

Comment: This question, suitably generalized, is discussed at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38337/. [Searching our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dummy+difference+interpretation) turns up a few hundred closely related posts: please look some of them over.

Comment: @Charles: Is it $Y = \beta_{2}X_{2}+ \epsilon-\beta_{1}X_{1}+\epsilon = \beta_{2}X_{2}-\beta_{1}X_{1} = \beta_2-\beta_1$?

Comment: @topguypoland. yes

Comment: @charles No: the two instances of "$\epsilon$" on the left hand side represent two independent random variables; they do not cancel like that (even when the second one is *subtracted* as intended). However, *when you apply the expectation operator* you obtain a correct statement.