Calculate $t$-statistics given coefficients + correlations
We have a simple multiple regression equation
$$
y=a+bx_1+cx_2+\varepsilon,
$$
where $a,b,c$ were estimated via OLS -- we know these values. Just like in my previous question (Calculate $R^2$ given estimated coefficients and $N$ only) I'm trying to figure out, is it enough information to calculate $t$ statistics for $x_1,x_2$ and decide on factors significance, given sample correlations $r_{x_1,x_2}, r_{x_1,y}, r_{x_2,y}$ only.
Is it true, that the information given is not enough to conclude on factors significance, since we lack $\sigma_{x_i}$'s?

Again, a search of our site will help you.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38337 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135201.  Shall we presume you also know $N$ in this case?  Otherwise, there's no hope ;-).

You don't have information about the variances of the variables.  Let's pretend we do and see how that affects the results given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/135240/919, which shows how to perform the regression using the full covariance matrix.
Because you are concerned only about the coefficients of the explanatory variables (and not about the intercept), without any loss of generality we may assume all variables are centered: their (empirical) means are zero.  Any change in variances can be expressed by right-multiplying the $n\times p$ design matrix $X$ by a positive diagonal $p\times p$ matrix $\Lambda$ and multiplying the response $Y$ by a non-negative number $\lambda.$ What happens to the regression solutions?
(Because this information is useful in its own right, I will be thorough and highlight the important results in numbered equations.)
The parameter estimates
$$b = (X^\prime X)^{-1} X^\prime Y$$
must become
$$b_0 = ((X\Lambda)^\prime (X\Lambda))^{-1} (X\Lambda)^\prime Y\lambda = \Lambda^{-1} (X^\prime X)^{-1} X^\prime Y\lambda = \Lambda^{-1} b \lambda.$$
(This is readily understandable as what a basic dimensional (units of measure) analysis predicts.)
Because $\lambda$ is a diagonal matrix -- let's write $\lambda_i = \lambda_{ii}$ for those elements -- this more simply says
$$b_{j0} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda_j}b_j,\ j = 1, 2, \ldots, p\tag{1}.$$
The residual standard error determined by
$$(n-p-1)s^2 = Y^\prime Y - b^\prime X^\prime Y$$
becomes
$$(n-p-1)s_0^2 = \lambda^2 Y^\prime Y - (\Lambda^{-1}b\lambda)^\prime (X\Lambda)^\prime Y\lambda = \lambda^2(Y^\prime Y - b^\prime X^\prime Y),$$
showing
$$s_0^2 = \lambda^2 s^2.\tag{2}$$
(This makes sense: rescaling $Y$ by $\lambda$ must scale all residuals by $\lambda^2$ but won't affect the fit.)
The variance-covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates
$$V = (X^\prime X)^{-1}s^2$$
thereby becomes
$$V_0 = ((X\Lambda)^\prime (X\Lambda)^{-1} s_0^2 = \lambda^2 \Lambda^{-1} (X^\prime X)^{-1} (\Lambda^\prime)^{-1} s^2 = \lambda^2 \Lambda^{-1} V (\Lambda^\prime)^{-1}.\tag{3}$$
The standard error of the estimate $b_j,$ for $j=1,2,\ldots, p,$ is the square root of the corresponding diagonal element,
$$\operatorname{se}(b_j) = \sqrt{V_{jj}}.$$
Because $\lambda$ is a diagonal matrix -- let's write $\lambda_i = \lambda_{ii}$ for those elements -- the foregoing transformation formula for $V$ to $V_0$ shows that the new standard error is
$$\operatorname{se}(b_{j0}) = \sqrt{V_{jj0}} = \sqrt{\lambda^2 \lambda_j^{-1} V_{jj}\lambda_j^{-1}} = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda_j}\operatorname{se}(b_j).\tag{4}$$
This is identical to the transformation law (1) for the coefficient estimates.  (Again, because the units of the standard errors are the same as the units of the coefficients, this result is immediately obtained from a dimensional analysis.)
The t-statistics are the ratios of the estimates to their standard errors, which thereby remain unchanged, because their numerators and denominators are multiplied by common values which cancel:
$$t_j = \frac{b_j}{\operatorname{se}(b_j)} = \frac{b_{j0}}{\operatorname{se}(b_{j0})}.$$
This demonstrates that

To obtain the t-statistics, you may treat the full correlation matrix (among all $X$'s and $Y$) as if it were the covariance matrix.

The solution to your problem, then, already is given in the thread referenced at the outset!
(Of course, to interpret those t statistics properly you need their degrees of freedom $n-p-1$ and therefore you need to know $n,$ the amount of data.)
